# `gathered` unexpectedly wider than its "natural" width

Tags: equations, multline, gather

I have a `gathered` environment inside a `multlined` environment inside an `equation` environment. For some reason the `gathered`-environment is wider than its natural width. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Equation looks like expected:

\begin{equation}
  \left\lvert
    \begin{multlined}
      \Pr\left[
        1 \gets A(s)
      \middle\vert
        s \gets F(G)
      \right]\\
      {} - \Pr\left[
        1 \gets A(s')
      \middle\vert
        (s', t) \gets S(G)
      \right]
    \end{multlined}
  \right\rvert
\end{equation}

Equation with unexpected wide \verb#gathered#-environment

\begin{equation}
\left\lvert
  \begin{multlined}
    \Pr\left[
      1 \gets A\left(
        \begin{gathered}% <-- This is the problematic environment
          s',\\
          m
        \end{gathered}
      \right)
    \middle\vert
      \begin{gathered}
        s \gets F,\\
        m \gets M
      \end{gathered}
    \right]\\
    {} - \Pr\left[
      1 \gets A\left(
        \begin{gathered}
          s'\\
          m
        \end{gathered}
      \right)
    \middle\vert
      \begin{gathered}
        s' \gets F,\\
        c  \gets G
      \end{gathered}\right]
  \end{multlined}
\right\rvert
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** I know I could workaround the problem by using an `array`-environment within the parentheses in the second equation. However, I deliberately refrained from that, because of "semantic" programming. I tried to follow the rule (mathematical) vectors are coded as `array`'s, a single equation or term that is too long for a single line is put into a `multline` and `gather` is for multiple equations without special alignment. Although,
`left( \begin{gathered}s',\\m\end{gathered}\right)` might appear as it was a vector, it is actually not. In the full code `s'` and `m` are two equations. I have shortened them down for the sake of this MWE. Hence, I would prefer to stay with `gathered`.

Also, I would like to know *what* goes wrong here.

Comment: And with `pmatrix`?

Comment: @Bernard Of course, it works with `pmatrix`. (I believe to have read that `pmatrix` is based on `array`.) However the same argument applies here: The code inside `gathered` is not a vector but a system of equations that are logically "and'ed". Hence, I would like to use `gathered`, because `gathered` is for systems of equations and `array` for vectors. Moreover, the horizontal padding around a `array` or `pmatrix` is slightly different than around a `gathered`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in mathtools and/or amsmath but a workaroud might be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Equation looks like expected:

\begin{equation}
  \left\lvert
    \begin{multlined}
      \Pr\left[
        1 \gets A(s)
      \middle\vert
        s \gets F(G)
      \right]\\
      {} - \Pr\left[
        1 \gets A(s')
      \middle\vert
        (s', t) \gets S(G)
      \right]
    \end{multlined}
  \right\rvert
\end{equation}

Equation with unexpected wide \verb#gathered#-environment

\newsavebox\oops
\savebox\oops{$\begin{gathered}% <-- This is the problematic environment
          s',\\
          m
        \end{gathered}$}
\begin{equation}
\left\lvert
  \begin{multlined}
    \Pr\left[
      1 \gets A\left(\usebox\oops    \right)
    \middle\vert
      \begin{gathered}
        s \gets F,\\
        m \gets M
      \end{gathered}
    \right]\\
    {} - \Pr\left[
      1 \gets A\left(
        \begin{gathered}
          s'\\
          m
        \end{gathered}
      \right)
    \middle\vert
      \begin{gathered}
        s' \gets F,\\
        c  \gets G
      \end{gathered}\right]
  \end{multlined}
\right\rvert
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The documentation mentions "Bug 2: Due to the way multilined is implemented, certain constructions does not work inside multlined.". gathered seems to be one of it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "Documentation" what's that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you need a german keyboard to find it, at some time I will buy you one ;-).